# Comparing two fields' values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this statement in Oracle:

```
select agnt_name,
       exporter_name
from
(
  select agnt_name,
         exporter_name
  from Exporters
  union all
  select agnt_name,
         exporter_name
  from agents
)
```

now if I add this condition:
`WHERE agnt_name = exporter_name`

My question is: Will the query compare the values in both fields & if they equal it'll show the records?
Or will this condition be like a join condition?

Comment: A: compare the values in both columns.

Comment: There is a mistake in your statement. In this inner query you should appropriately correct the syntax, inserting the keyword **FROM** where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no `join` in your query -- not even an implicit `join`.  Hence, adding the condition will just compare the values in the two columns in the same row.

Comment: not helped by the fact that there are no tables mentioned at all in the OP's SQL statement *{;-)